# golang regex match everything up to a "."

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to do some regex in go match everything up to the first `.`.

The string would be this:
`hostkafka1.kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=FailedProduceRequestsPerSec,topic=auto.tooling.files.received.v1.MeanR^Cost","metric_path":"dsdpecard01kfk06.kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=FailedProduceRequestsPerSec,topic=credit-card.servicing.accounts.authorized-user.created.v1.MeanRate","type":null,"region":"us-east-1`

and I want to match `hostkafka1`

I can use `/.+?(?=\.)/` in other languages but can't get it to work in golang...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match everything from the start of the string that is not a period `.` with the following:

```
m := regexp.MustCompile(`^[^.]+`).FindString(s)
```

Playground Link: https://play.golang.org/p/OlPxIcrpmWx

This works because:

- the first `^` indicates the beginning of the string
- the `[^.]` indicates matching a character that is not a period
- the `+` is the repetition operator to indicate more than one

This will automatically end the match when a `.` is encountered.

If you want to ensure a period exists you can do the following:

```
m := regexp.MustCompile(`^(.+?)\.`).FindStringSubmatch(s)[1]
```

Playground Link: https://play.golang.org/p/oK0OvJzR2Ky

This works a bit differently than above in that it needs to match a period and captures everything before it.

- the `\.` at the end requires matching a period
- the `()` capture group allows exclude the matching period in the result
- the `.` in the parens indicates any character
- the `+?` indicates a lazy repetition to stop as soon as the condition is met, here matching a literal period `\.`

Answer (score 7):

There is really no reason to bust out the regex engine for such a trivial task. You are not dealing with a regular language. As evidenced by your question it is much clearer to write (and will run faster):

```
if n := strings.IndexByte(s, '.'); n >= 0 {
    fmt.Println(s[:n])
} else {
    // no match
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/fVmbERaz2SN